# Best strategy on buying champions and runes in LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends

I started playing LoL some time ago, recently my friend wanted to start as well, and he asked me if he should purchase some RP (he didnt even have an account back then). This made me realize that I actually have no idea what to spend RP on and when to buy things.

So I wrote down a few questions and I thought I might get some answers:

- Should I spend my IP only on runes or as well on champions?
- When does it make sence to start buying RP?
- What should I buy with RP, champions or boosts?
- Should I only buy champions I already played on a free week?
- When should I start buying runes or champions (which level)?

I don't think this is really opinion based because I guess that there is a "best system" to have a perfect combination of spending money and having good champions, runes etc.

Comment: Good question sir, give me a few minutes to accumulate an answer.

Comment: It really depends on how much money you want to invest. If you want to get away as cheaply as possible, only buy skins with RP. If money is no issue, only buy Runes with IP and do whatever you want with leftover IP, saving a bit of money in the long run. Spending RP on stuff that is currently on sale seems obvious if you plan on having everything at some point. Bundles are permanently on sale basically. From there, it's just a question of where in the spectrum between no money and infinite money you see yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all all of you questions depend on your personal preference. But I'll come to a conclusion after answering your questions.

**Should I spend my IP only on runes or as well on champions?**

This depends on what champions you like to play. You can get up to lvl 30 in League of Legends before the game considers you maxed level. At level 20 you unlock the best possible runes, marks, glyphs, and seals. As you can see the earlier runes give you a bonus but it's usually not worth getting them since you're going to replace them after a few days of playing anyway. The thing to probably note as a "new" player is that you dont need to buy runes before 20. The difference those runes make is neglect-able and not worth compared to their cost.

"*So what do i do with all of the IP i earn then?*"

Well that's a good question. Before you hit level 20 you obviously earn a lot of IP simply by winning and losing matches. Now how much you spend of it is entirely up to you. You could decide you only want 1 champion and after that you save for the runes you're going to buy once you hit level 20. That's a possibility. This is however not the most exciting way of playing the game. (once again its all personal preference, but) personally i prefer(ed) to buy the champions i 'liked' to play until level 18 or so (17, 18, 19) and then save your IP for when you hit lvl 20 to buy runes. More about this on your other questions.

**When does it make sense to start buying RP?**

League of Legends is a free to play game. You can get to the same level if either pay or don't. I can try to explain this but the league of legends wiki has the perfect explanation already:

> They can be purchased with real money and are used to purchase in-game things to add convenience, extra customization options, or diversity to the experience. Examples of things that can be purchased with Riot Points are champions, alternate champion skins, or boosts, which are modifiers that increase the rate at which you gain Influence Points or Summoner Experience Points. Apart from purchasing champions and extra rune pages, which are both also purchasable with Influence Points, Riot Points cannot be used to directly affect gameplay.

Especially note the last line "Riot Points cannot be used to directly affect gameplay." Meaning that you have the exact same cooldowns, costs, movement speed etc as all other summoners in the game (with the exception of the runes).

**What should I buy with RP, champions or boosts?**

Once again what you decide to buy with your RP is entirely up to yourself. Buying champions with RP is only if you don't want to go through the trouble of getting the IP since every champion is unlocked with IP as well as RP. The thing i use RP for are skins. I now own nearly every skin in the game and i enjoy playing with the skins as well. You could also buy boosters but this only increases either your IP or EXP.

**Should I only buy champions I already played on a free week?**

Buying a champion which you've already played does give you an edge in playing that champ but most importantly it ensures you 'like' to play that champion. For example i bought the champion Lucian right when it got released but i didn't like to play with him. Should you ONLY buy champions you've already played? No, but its up to you.

**When should I start buying runes or champions (which level)?**

At level 20 (see your first question).

If you have any other questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know how much IP it takes to get 3 full rune pages? I personally have to say that I can't imagine spending money on skins yet, but since it's a free game and people get something for supporting it, it seems legit :D

Comment: @RandomDisplayName The price of a completed list depends on what runes you buy since they all differ in prices. You can find their prices here : http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_runes.

Comment: no problem, happy to help ;)

Comment: Now a sad addendum: having bought some crap/cheap runes (not level 20 yet), what do I do with them? I tried merging most together with some success.

Comment: @ashes999 They are literally useless now. At least you can filter them out so you don't see them in the rune page creator.

Comment: @Katustrawfic can't they be eventually merged/whatever into useful runes?

Comment: You can but you need three tier 2's to merge into a single _random_ tier 3 rune. Rather than spend money on tier 2's to merge into random tier 3's that you may or may not use, you're better off buying the tier 3's you actually want/will use.

Answer (score 4):

When buying stuff keep one thing in mind: **You cannot buy runes with riot points!** This is pretty heavy since runes are amongst the most important things in LoL at lvl 30.

### TL;DR

- Buy runes at level 20 for AP/AD/Tank and only buy champions with IP after you have at least 2 Rune pages.
- Buy a champion bundle for RP.
- If you can afford it buy RP until you have about 80 champions and always keep an eye on sales.
- Don't Waste money on Boosts.
- If you know a champion already It's worth buying it of course and If you're interested in one just buy it aswell. If you're not sure about whether or not you will like the champion don't buy it immediately (watch some playstyle videos first)
- Play at least once a day to maximize your IP gain (FWOTD bonus)

### A bit more detailed answer

You basically want to save up for at least 2 runepages which will greatly increase your chance of winning. For me personally I reached platinum Elo with only 3 rune pages so It's really an investment that's worth it. You should start buying runes at level 20.

When it comes to buying champions you should probably buy a Champion bundle. In a bundle you will have 20 champions and a skin for the price of roughly 5 champions. The problem is that you have to spend real money for bundles.

If you don't want to spend real money I'd suggest to buy runes first and then champions you know well. Also the price of a champion doesn't determine it's strenght. Some 450 IP champions are just as good as those who cost 6300 IP (if not better).

You shouldn't be spending RP on boosts unless you want to play for 3-30 days straight. You will get enough IP to afford stuff with it. And once you have enough games you will notice that IP gains are pretty high (I got about 300k IP right now and I have no Idea what to do with it).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm afraid I can only accept one answer and both answers atm were really good so I had to decide which one I accept. I already bought the bundle and I'm saving IP for rune's, so I guess I'm on the right path :)

Answer (score 2):

### The Most Efficient Use of IP/RP

Runes require IP but champions can be bought with IP or RP.  The earlier champions are relatively cheap IP/RP, but the later ones are 6300 IP, a large amount of IP that takes a long time to acquire.  Luckily, 3 champions are on sale every 3 days, cutting the RP but not IP price.

**Since runes can only be bought with IP, spend your IP on the Greater runes starting at level 20 and use RP to buy champions from the most expensive tiers (>3150 IP) that are on sale.**

If money is no object, you can buy a large pool of champions in only a few weeks.  The cheap champions can also be bought with RP, but they are cheaper than some of the Quintessences, so just buy those with IP to make your dollars/RP last longer.  If you want to further stretch your dollar, research champions that are not meta friendly or have low win percentages and skip buying those, prioritizing the champs with high win rates, ban rates, or are common picks.  (use lolking.net)

**Once you've bought general use runes for most champs (armor seals, damage marks, magic resist blues, etc.) start buying more champions with IP.**

If you are new to the game, you will undoubtedly buy champions that you don't like or are not skilled using when following this method. If you really want to become skilled at this game and climb the ranked ladder, you will have to become proficient and familiar with a large champion pool anyways, so it will be worth it in the long run.

**The Digital collector's pack, Starter pack, and Champions bundle are worth the RP, but include many cheap champions that could be bought with IP.**

If you want cheap champions fast, buy the bundles.  The Champions bundle is especially worthwhile because it includes more expensive champions, while the starter pack includes many cheap ones.  I'd personally buy the Starter champions with IP and use RP for the other packs to stretch my RP for sales.

**Use RP to buy a rune page bundle.**

Rune pages are not cheap at 6300 IP.  This is really the only place where Riot forces us to spend real cash on their game, otherwise it's rough saving up the IP.  This just makes it easier on you and accelerates your learning of runes as you have more room for experimentation.